# SSRS: Enumerate available reports - only works with UseDefaultCredetials

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, credentials

I'm trying to generate a list of available reports from an SSRS 2008 installation, using code as below:

```
ReportingService2005 rs = new ReportingService2005();
rs.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

CatalogItem[] items = rs.ListChildren("/", true);

foreach(CatalogItem ci in items)
{
   if (ddlReport.Type == ItemTypeEnum.Report)
      ddlReport.Items.Add(ci.Path);
}
```

This works fine.

If I set UseDefaultCredentials to false and specify rs.Credentials as System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials this also works fine.

However, if I set UseDefaultCredentials to false and specify specific credentials I get 401 unauthorized errors back.

The credentials I am trying to use definitely have access to the report server, and I am at a loss to proceed further.

Comment: I'd like to delete this question, however there's no indication of how I can do so (neither on this page, nor the FAQ).

Comment: @M Wrench, if you look immediately below the set of tags at the end of your post, you should see some text in light grey: `link|edit|close|delete|flag`. Clicking on the `delete` should delete the post.

Comment: How did you fix this? I got the same problem

Comment: Instead of deleting you should add your answer for future users to benefit from.